# In a Google Sheet tab created based on a sheet row, how do I reference a specific row in a formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using following App Script to generate new tabs based on items in a `People` tab in my spreadsheet.

```
function add_sheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var start_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('People');
  var template_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('_Template_');

  // get list of values from the main sheet 
  var names = start_sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat().filter(String);
  var attr1s = start_sheet.getRange('B2:B').getValues().flat().filter(String);
  var attr2s = start_sheet.getRange('C2:C').getValues().flat().filter(String);

  while(names.length) {
    var name = names.shift();
    var attr1 = attr1s.shift();
    var attr2 = attr2s.shift();

    // try to pick existed sheet with the name
    try { var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name); dest_sheet.getRange('A1') }

    // create the sheet if there is no sheet with this name
    catch(e) { var dest_sheet = template_sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(name) } 

    dest_sheet.getRange('B2').setValue(name);
    dest_sheet.getRange('B3').setValue(attr1);
    dest_sheet.getRange('B4').setValue(attr2);
  }
}
```

My `People` sheet looks like this (no formulas)

[image: People Tab for this question]

My template tab looks like this

[image: Template tab for this question]

Cell `B5` has the following formula: `=SUM(B3:B4)`. Other than this, currently `B2:B4` will be populated by the script above.

A generated tab looks like this after the script runs:

[image: Individual user tab]

My script works. However, once these sheets are generated, they are disconnected from the `People` tab. If I want to change an attribute value, it is not updated in the appropriate sheet, meaning I need to do it in both the people tab and in the individual tab.

If I were to create these tabs manually, I'd put a formula in `B2` that looks similar to this to ensure the child tab was updated when the `People` one was: `=People!A2`

How can I adjust my script to link to the associated information with a formula in the template? My goal is to have manually inserted data on these individual user tabs and I don't want to have to re-generate the portion that I can do automatically everytime something updates. I would like to keep the two sections in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I understand that you want to keep values updated in each person's sheet whenever an "Attribute" value is updated in the "People" sheet.

To give you an idea, in the "_Template_'" sheet, cell "B3", I entered the following formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2,People!A1:C,{2,3},FALSE)))
```

And updated the script to this:

```
function add_sheets2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var start_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('People');
  var template_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('_Template_');

  // get list of values from the main sheet 
  var names = start_sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat().filter(String);

  while(names.length) {
    var name = names.shift();

    // try to pick existed sheet with the name
    try { var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name); dest_sheet.getRange('A1') }

    // create the sheet if there is no sheet with this name
    catch(e) { var dest_sheet = template_sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(name) } 

    dest_sheet.getRange('B2').setValue(name);
  }
}
```

Run the script and it will create the respective sheets for each person, update any "Attribute" value in the "People" sheet and it should be reflected on each individual user sheet.